# How share data in WCF webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, static, thread-safety

In order to call webservices dynamicly, I use [WCF Dynamic Proxy from Microsoft](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/netfxsamples/Wiki/Print.aspx?title=WCF%20samples&version=8&action=Print)

If I understood properly how it works, the code load the wsdl and compile on system class in order to consume distant webservice. I put this code in a "generic webservice". Its goal is to call any webservice with a request in parameter, and respond the answer of the webservice called.

But a problem appears : each request to this "generic webservice" pulls a new compilation of the proxy, and use time and ressources of the server.

My objective is to save instance of each proxies during a laps of time, and renew the instance when this laps is reached.

After few hours of googling, I found two ways :

- Use my WCF webservice "by session", but I don't find any tutorial which explains how create easily the session layer
- Use a singleton in order to save my datas and mutualize them with all instances of webservice

I exclude the first solution because I don't know how to do this. So I decided to use the second way.

There is my implementation :

- FactoryTest is the singleton, contening the hashtable with instances
- ProxyTest is the class which contains information about each instances of distant webservices

There is the code of FactoryTest :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WcfSamples.DynamicProxy;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;

namespace WS_Generic
{
    public sealed class FactoryTest
    {
        private static object syncRoot = new Object();
        private static Hashtable hashFactory = new Hashtable();

        public static DynamicProxy getProxy(String sServiceWsdl, String sContract)
        {
            if (hashFactory[sServiceWsdl] == null || ((ProxyTest)hashFactory[sServiceWsdl]).getTimeFromCreation().TotalSeconds > 60 * 60 * 6)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (hashFactory[sServiceWsdl] == null || ((ProxyTest)hashFactory[sServiceWsdl]).getTimeFromCreation().TotalSeconds > 60 * 60 * 6)
                    {
                        hashFactory.Add(sServiceWsdl, new ProxyTest(sServiceWsdl, sContract));
                    }
                }
            }

            return ((ProxyTest)hashFactory[sServiceWsdl]).getProxy();
        }

        public static bool isProxyExists(String sServiceWsdl, String sContract)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                return hashFactory[sServiceWsdl] == null ? false : true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is the code of ProxyTest :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using WcfSamples.DynamicProxy;

namespace WS_Generic
{
    public class ProxyTest
    {
        private DateTime instanceCreation;
        private String sServiceWsdl;
        private String sContract;
        private DynamicProxyFactory factory;
        private volatile DynamicProxy proxy;

        public ProxyTest(String sServiceWsdl, String sContract)
        {
            instanceCreation = DateTime.Now;
            this.sServiceWsdl = sServiceWsdl;
            this.sContract = sContract;
            this.factory = new DynamicProxyFactory(this.sServiceWsdl);
            this.proxy = factory.CreateProxy(this.sContract);
        }

        public DynamicProxy getProxy()
        {
            return proxy;
        }

        public TimeSpan getTimeFromCreation()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Subtract(instanceCreation);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the webservice seems to reset the static status of FactoryTest after each call. So each time I called the webservice, my hashtable is empty and the factory create a new instance.

If anybody had already the problem of share datas between differents threads in WCF webservice (and found the solution), thanks in advance to give me some tips :)

PS : Sorry for my english, that's not my native language

Answer (score 0):

If you store data in static variable WCF itself will not affect their purging. The problem must be somewhere else (application restart, app domain recreation, etc.).

Btw. this solution has only very limited usage because long living shared proxies should not be used and in many cases it can result in unexpected behavior. It can perhaps work only for services using `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: so if it's a wrong way to backup instances of proxies, what is the best solution to keep generic aspect and avoid the compilation time (about 1 sec, that is a lot when we speak in transaction time).

Comment: I'm not sure if there is solution for your scenario. You want generic solution but in the same time you don't want to pay for generic solution. Either remove one of your requirements or go to lower level = no service specific proxy and working with Message class directly. You will have to find how to get binding information from WSDL and you will have to handle SOAP request / response content at your own.